# Vertically Center Header Image On All Devices Without Overlapping Content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

having a bit of a mare with something that should be simple. 
Basically I would like an element consisting of an image and some text below to be both vertically and horizontally centered. I need this to be consistent across all devices as a kind of welcome screen, perhaps using percentages?

Below that in my code is the next element which are some nav tabs, however the problem with my code currently is that it causes overlapping of content so looking for a little guidance. I can't put a fixed height in the code as viewports will vary.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thanks guys.

**HTML**

```
<header class="header-content text-center">
    <img src="assets/img/sample.png"/>
    <h1>some text</h1>
    <h2>here is some more text that I am working on blah</h2>
  </header>

  <section class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
      <li data-toggle="tab" class="active"><a href="#home">Test</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">test1</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">test2</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">test3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>test</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>test1</h3>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>test2</h3>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>test3</h3>
        <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

**CSS**

```
header.header-content{
    color:#fff; 
    margin: auto; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use breakpoints.  Basically, it works like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    /* Fill with styling rules */
}
```

`@media` is used to define different rules for different devices, screen widths, etc.

`screen` is self explanatory.

`(max-width: 1000px)` means that anything 1000 pixels and down will have those styling rules applied to them.  An alternative is to use `min-width`, which does the opposite.

Comment: Yeah i was just hoping there was a better overall way to approach it and save having to do additional breakpoint related css. Mobiles, Ipads etc all have diff screen heights so just hoping for a better approach

Comment: You could always use percentages, although breakpoints are usually the better way to go, especially when you get into the font-size (not possible or not very easy to do with percentages).  I guess you could use a combination of both.